# Change notifications in nested SVN working copies propagate to top level

Tags: svn, nested, repository, tortoisesvn

I have two SVN repositories: repo1 and repo2
My directory structure is as such:

- root
- - repo1_folder1
- - - repo1_subfolder1 (here I set up svn:ignore=* property for whole content)
- - - - repo2_folder1
- - - - - repo2_subfolder1

Let's say I modify something in repo2_subfolder1.

If I do commit on repo1_folder1 it successfully only checks down to repo1_subfolder1 (because of ignore) and finds there are no changes.
However, the folder icon of repo1_folder1 is still red.

I am using TortoiseSVN 1.8.6 client on Windows 7.

Can you please tell me what I can do so that bottom level changes in one repository will not be visible by top level second repository?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this two nested working copies which you called "svn checkout" on separately? Or is repo2 actually somewhere within the repo1 folder structure?

Comment: Hi Ben.  In directory tree, repo2 is under repo1.  From SVN perspective, they are completely independent repositories (even on two different servers).  I thought, by setting svn:ignore=* on repo1_subfolder1 level, existence of all underlying content would be hidden from repo1, in every matter.

Comment: Folder icons some time show incorrect information. Check may be this  is the case: http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#ovlwrong

Comment: Hi Sergey.  Thank you for the link.  Lot's of great information.  Unfortunately, that specific paragraph, is not my case.  I am familiar with slow responsiveness of SVN client in regards to status updates.  I got used to that already :).  But this is really very special case.  I think I will just moved both of them under separate directories.
The reason why they were nested in the first place was because inner one (company code base) was done first and outer one (my personal backup) was done after and it just happened to contain the first one.